# steadily slowing ajax calls to WCF service from javascript

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, jquery, wcf

I have a WCF service that I am calling to using jQuery 1.4.2 (polling it actually every second or so).  Over time, the ajax calls slow.  Initial request to a method are around ~30ms, but over about a half hour i can watch using Opera's DragonFly (and verified with chrome's tools too) my request times slowly increase.  In about a half hour i go from ~30ms request time to ~300ms request time.

At first i thought it was the service i wrote, so I changed the method to just return a value, no calculations or anything:

```
public int DoSomething(int id)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

I was pretty surprised to see that the behavior is the same: A steady increase in request time.  I know this is pretty vague, but any pointers for trouble shooting something like this?  if its not my method, who is the likely candidate?

Im using .NET 3.5sp1 & C#

**edit:**  To clarify, I am using jQuery's $.ajax method to make the call, and its the actual request time that is slowing, the response is always pretty much ~0ms.

**edit 2:** I have fixed the memory issue mentioned in the comments with Jon Hanna & still my request times grow.

Comment: So it sounds like you ruled out the service side of things.  What does your jQuery code look like?  Are you taking the return value and appending DOM elements to your page, adding new animations, setting timers, etc.?  Sounds like the client-side code may be the problem.

Comment: Its the actual ajax request that is slowing, not the response.

Comment: Can you post your jQuery ajax code and how you're handling the response?  If you have a large number of selectors in your ajax call and you're manipulating the DOM on success, that could be slowing things down on making the request (and explain why the response is always 0ms).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the memory being consumed by the browser as it goes on? It might be worth keeping an eye on this, and see if it increases much as time goes on.

You'll want a fresh browser (no point measuring after you've had your YouTube videos of your favourite musician's popular hits open in different tabs) that's been allowed to climb through any initial memory-grabs and then runs your script.

If this is an issue, then look at pooling your javascript objects, especially the XHR itself, at making sure events aren't bound to handlers and then ignored, and that you aren't continually adding to the DOM of the host document.

Comment: The browser memory is going up, but i dont know if its significant.  ~3.5MB in about ~35-40min.  jQuery is the one controlling the actual ajax request using its $.ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

it is nature of WCF that it's slower than anyother methods.
have u try .ashx

it is similar to normal aspx page but ashx has no html page. just purely code behind. perfect for execute url with query string and return it in string or json form.

ex
http://localhost/test.ashx?get=test

in ashx
return 'passed';

i usually use it with jQuery.load('test.ashx?get=test', function(...){}) with this method, i dont have to worry about $.ajax crap anymore